# How to setup approvals for each deployment when it is scheduled in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I want to set approvals for each deployment triggered/scheduled in Azure DevOps.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Click in the thunder icon on each environment and set approvals. did you know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what the trigger type is, the setting of approval are all same.

Just open the pre-deployment conditions of each deployment, and then add the approver account or group name.  And it also same in post-deployment conditions to set post-deployment approval.

[image]